# Why is TeXample.net TikZ-specific?

Tags: examples

Link: http://www.texample.net/

I'm reluctant to ask this here, since it is not *about TeX*.  However, I consider it a *very* useful tool when I need it, and it's a wonderful idea, I just wish it were more general.

I've used TeXample when I needed help with a complicated graphic, and I'm almost sure you have too (if you hopped on the PGF gravy train).  However, I've also seen a bunch of awesome stuff done with LaTeX in general (you can tell by the pixels) and I would love nothing more than to emulate it, customize it, and <strike>brag about</strike>share it with my friends and colleagues.

Is there any specific, technical reason why TeXample cannot host generic examples of LaTeX's abilities, essentially becoming a definitive showcase of the most impressive typography that LaTeX is capable of?

I've contacted TeXample via the web-form, but I'm sure that the developers are on here somewhere and probably have a good reason one way or the other.

Comment: I think you should ask @StefanKottwitz who maintains TeXample. As far as I know TeXample _was_ focussed on TikZ when Kjell Magne Fauske launched (and maintained) it but isn't any more, at least not exclusively. It just not reflected in the contents, yet.

Comment: Recently Stefan pointed out, that he would be glad getting examples for MetaPost (this was the topic, when he wrote this): http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3415.

Comment: I noticed that Stefan was the maintainer, and would value his input immensely.  While MetaPost (and pstricks, probably, so it doesn't feel left out) would be a great addition to the site, it would still then be graphics-only.

Comment: @Closers, is there anything I can do to make this question more on-topic, or is this simply too nebulous?

Comment: I don’t really see why this should be off-topic. It is, unlike the majority of the questions here, not about a *TeX code or installation related problem, but more about an aspect of the *TeX community, but that’s still valid, even though it might not be our favorite kind of question. It’s sort of similar in style to [How do package authors find the time?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37366). Voting to reopen.

Comment: As every graphics package authors/sites have their own examples maintained by respective authors for eg: [PSTricks examples](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples), [MetaPost-ConTeXt's native graphics](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/MetaPost) has [metapost examples](http://tex.loria.fr/prod-graph/zoonekynd/metapost/metapost.html) and [asymptote examples](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/), hence teXample.net might have `pgf based` tikz pgfplots and related gnuplot etc and much more. I think texample.net is open to others but it becomes double hosting it.

Comment: Do you want to change its domain name to `tikzexample.org`?

Comment: @texenthusiast you raised a really good point about hosting---as good and altruistic as our intentions are, these things still cost cold hard cash.  Karlsstudents, would changing it to `*.org` change anything monetarily? (I'm hardly familiar with web services, etc.)

Comment: For reference, `.org` is *not* taken, but it may not be advisable to change the domain name at this stage, per bookmarks etc.  `.org` still costs money, according to GoDaddy (naturally).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Partly summarising comments]

TeXample.net was set up by Kjell Magne Fauske to showcase 'TikZ stuff', and like any personal website he got to decide what it was about. Kjell was interested in TikZ and how it could be used, and provided a lot of the first examples himself. He also encouraged people to submit other examples, and over time it became a great place to find TikZ stuff.

Kjell handed the site over a while ago to our own [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/stefan-kottwitz), and Stefan has indicated he's happy to extend the site to other areas of the TeX world. However, there are already places for some other aspects: for example the [PSTricks website](http://tug.org/PSTricks) has lots of useful PSTricks demos.

Adding additional content means getting it and keeping it organised: a simple 'dumping ground' doesn't work so well. At the same time, you have to take into account that sometimes division is a good thing: TeXample is certainly graphics-focussed and I suspect would make a less-than-ideal site for collecting up other stuff.

Just to mention every graphics have their examples maintained by respective package authors/fan sites for eg:  [Syracuse website](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/) by Group of Users of Linux to Poitiers has PSTricks and MetaPost examples collection

- [PSTricks examples](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples), [Syracuse's PSTricks gallery](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/) and Manuel Luque's [excellent PSTricks blog](http://www.pstricks.blogspot.com)
- [MetaPost-ConTeXt's native graphics](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/MetaPost) - has [MetaPost examples](http://tex.loria.fr/prod-graph/zoonekynd/metapost/metapost.html) and also [Syracuse's MetaPost gallery](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/metapost/)
- [Asymptote examples](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/)
- [TeXample Tikz gallery](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) might have `pgf` based `tikz` `pgfplots` and related `gnuplot` etc and much more.

In my view `TeXample.net` is open to others but it becomes double hosting it.