# What non-free books are available and recommended?

Tags: books, big-list

Once convinced, for example by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111805/412) answer, that I should **buy** a book on (La)TeX and friends, its is time to decide which one... This [big list](http://tug.org/books/) misses some ranking, and make it hard to choose.

This [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/412) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66/412) one provides some details, but it seems that they mainly mention *free* references.

So, what would you recommend to **buy**?

Comment: The [book reviews from TUGboat](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/listkeyword.html#CatTAGBookReviews) should be of some help.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/412 This question you link mentions both free and pay-for references. If you're so interested in buying a non-free book, and it turns out the best ones are free, why not download them instead and make a donation to their authors? The top answers (most upvoted) are about free books for obvious reasons, but some excellent non-free books are listed as well.

Comment: This [TeX Community Poll question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1571) about TeX/LaTeX books is also related...

Comment: It depends on taste/budget/knowledge levels. Please choose from [TUG book list](http://www.tug.org/books/) based on [book preview/reviews](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/listkeyword.html#CatTAGBookReviews) as suggested by [barbara beeton's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111703/why-should-i-buy-a-tex-latex-guide-book/111805#comment246454_111805). Have a look at [TeX community polls](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1571/15717) on Books. Some [suggestions based on knowledge levels](http://www.macrotex.net/texbooks/)

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97519/what-sequence-of-documents-should-i-read-to-know-all-of-tex-and-then-latex/97556#97556

Answer (score 5):

I **strongly** recommend

> > The LaTeX Companion (Tools and Techniques for Computer Typesetting)
>
> [Frank Mittelbach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10109/frank-mittelbach), Michel Goossens, Johannes Braams, [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle), Chris Rowley, Addison-Wesley, 2004.

Comment: who are those people?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle these are people that sometimes hang out at TeX conferences (or used to).