# Write mathematics in a caption

Tags: math-mode

Sometimes I want to write mathematics (like `\in` - is an element of).
While the element-sign is shown, LaTeX shows errors when compiling saying:

> Missing $ inserted.
>
> Extra }, or forgotten $.
>
> Missing } inserted.

When then surrounding any `\in` with `\[` and `\]` it adds a blank line before and after the line containing `\in`. I only want to have the simple sign, not the additional space.

This is my code without `\[`...`\]` around the `\in`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}

    \underline{function myAlgo} $(G)$\;
    \Input{A Graph $G = (V, E)$ with v in V}
    \Output{nothing yet}
    \tcp{does it for ever v in V}
    doSth()\;
    return $G$\;
    \caption{Does sth for every vertex v \in V}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what you probably want is `$v \in V$`.  the `\in` *must* be in math mode (the part inside `$...$` as you have already used correctly for `$G = (V, E)$`).  since `\in` is recognized as math, tex will switch into math mode if it isn't already there, and will therefore report a missing `$` when it encounters something that *can't* be math.

Comment: thats it thanks, unfortunately you wrote a comment instead of an answer, so I cannot denote you with +1

Comment: i've posted an answer now.  i commented instead of answering for two reasons: first, this is a really elementary question for which the information can be found in any good introduction to tex, and second, it has probably been answered here already, and is thus a duplicate, but i'm in a situation where i can't easily check.  i'll add a link to a good introduction to my answer.

Comment: hi, yes of course I thought of that but I may am too silly to find them. I gave up after about 20 minutes of searching for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you probably want is `$v \in V$`.

the `\in` must be in math mode (the part inside `$...$` as you have already used correctly for `$G = (V, E)$`). since \in is recognized as math, tex will switch into math mode if it isn't already there, and will therefore report a missing $ when it encounters something that can't be math.

this is an elementary principle of tex, so reading a good introduction
would be a good idea.  i recommend the [books by nicola talbot](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/index.html).  some other good advice is given at [Why should I buy a TeX/LaTeX guide book?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111703/579).